# Bricked Nexus 7 in Recovery Mode

Tags: adb, nexus-7, boot, twrp, partitions

I have a Nexus 7 2012 grouper in recovery mode (TWRP). I have wiped the /system /cache and /data partitions and believe it has wiped the /boot partition. When I go to file manager, it says the /boot folder is empty. I don't want to reboot the device because it may render it unusable. What should I do?

Comment: Not every partition can be formatted. I can't remember the correct technical term though. Perhaps somebody else can remind us that. Your boot partition would remain intact unless you overwrite it. Now, keep the phone plugged in to power source, use a PC to download a flashable zip for a ROM and side load it in device. Alternatively, even if you power off the device or reboot it, it's not like it would be the end of the world for your device. You can always use magical key sequence (key combo) to boot into recovery or fastboot mode.

Comment: BTW, you can download the stock ROM from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) and flash it using fastboot mode too.

Comment: I've just flashed the latest cyanogenmod grouper nightly by putting the zip on my device from my PC then installing it using twrp. I've heard something about the boot.img needing to be intact. I just want to be fully sure my device will survive a reboot.

Comment: If you flashed that ROM then it would have overwritten the boot partition with its own boot.img. So at this moment, your boot partition contains a kernel image. To satisfy yourself to the fullest, extract boot.img from that zip and flash it using Install option of TWRP. Choose Install Image in drop-down menu and select the boot image -> boot partition and done. Oh, and that boot directory is empty here as well, even though I've a perfectly running device.

Comment: OK, I've done that, and it said `[IMAGE FLASH COMPLETED]` . I'm going to restart it now. Shitting myself because I've already perma-bricked a phone. Not having a tablet go too lol.

Comment: It worked! Thanks :D . Never been so happy to see that smiley blue alien thing in my life!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the factory image for your device here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Follow the instructions at the top of the page to flash. Note that the WIFI and Mobile versions have different images. Make sure to use `flash-all` otherwise the bootloader and radio will remain the same and the images won't flash.

Another option if you want to keep your ROM would be to download the factory image for the version you have on the device and flash only the `boot.img` using `fastboot flash boot boot.img` instead of `flash-all`. That should restore your boot but you have to know which version you have on the device.